# how can i get out of this loop?

Tags: racket

```
(define (desplazamiento a b c)
  (cond

    ((equal? c #t) (begin
                    ((draw-solid-rectangle ventana) (make-posn a b) 40 40 "blue")
                    (sleep 0.5)
                    ((clear-solid-rectangle ventana) (make-posn a b) 40 40 )
                    (cond ((= b 160) (desplazamiento a b #f))
                          )
                    (desplazamiento (+ a 40) (+ b 40) c)
                    
                    ))
        ((equal? c #f) (begin
                    ((draw-solid-rectangle ventana) (make-posn a b) 40 40 "blue")
                    (sleep 0.5)
                    ((clear-solid-rectangle ventana) (make-posn a b) 40 40 )
                    (cond ((= b 0) (desplazamiento a b #t))
                          )
                    (desplazamiento (+ a 40) ( b 40) c)
                    
                    ))
        
        
        )
    )
 

(desplazamiento 0 0 #t )
```

I have tried to put another conditional that with which I defined "d" as true but when I converted it to false the same did not exit the loop

Comment: Figure out under what conditions you want it to stop, and when those conditions are present, *don't* call `desplazamiento` again.

Comment: Should read https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html too.

Comment: You added the stop term as the very first? If you added it last one of the two first terms has already been hit since the second predicate is `(not first)`. I practice it could just been an else term since we already know that this far it was not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the behaviour you are looking for?

```
#lang scheme

(define (desplazamiento a b c)
  (cond

    ((equal? c #t) (begin
                    (sleep 1)
                    (display "a = ")(display a)
                    (display "; b = ") (display b) (display "\n")

                    (cond
                      ((= b 160) (begin
                          (desplazamiento a b #f)
                      ))
                      ((= 160 160) (begin
                         (desplazamiento (+ a 40) (+ b 40) c)
                      ))
                    )

                    
                    
                    ))
        ((equal? c #f) (begin
                    (sleep 1.5)
                    (display "you reached the false conditional case!\n")
                    ))
        
        
        )
    )
 

(desplazamiento 0 0 #t )
```